AWS Lambda Function Returns Empty Event Object When Testing with Postman
I have an AWS Lambda function written in Node.js that logs the event and returns it in the response. When I test this function using the AWS API Gateway test feature, it works perfectly and returns the full event object. However, when I test it with Postman, the event object appears empty in the response. Here is the code for the Lambda function:
export const handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  // Log the headers to CloudWatch
  console.log('Received events:', event);

  // Create a response object containing the headers
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2), // Pretty-print the JSON
  };

  // Return the response
  return response;
};

When tested with the AWS API Gateway, the response looks like this:
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\n  \"version\": \"2.0\",\n  \"routeKey\": \"$default\",\n  \"rawPath\": \"/path/to/resource\",\n  \"rawQueryString\": \"parameter1=value1&parameter1=value2&parameter2=value\",\n  \"cookies\": [\n    \"cookie1\",\n    \"cookie2\"\n  ],\n  \"headers\": {\n    \"Header1\": \"value1\",\n    \"Header2\": \"value1,value2\"\n  },\n  \"queryStringParameters\": {\n    \"parameter1\": \"value1,value2\",\n    \"parameter2\": \"value\"\n  },\n  \"requestContext\": {\n    \"accountId\": \"123456789012\",\n    \"apiId\": \"api-id\",\n    \"authentication\": {\n      \"clientCert\": {\n        \"clientCertPem\": \"CERT_CONTENT\",\n        \"subjectDN\": \"www.example.com\",\n        \"issuerDN\": \"Example issuer\",\n        \"serialNumber\": \"a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1:a1\",\n        \"validity\": {\n          \"notBefore\": \"May 28 12:30:02 2019 GMT\",\n          \"notAfter\": \"Aug  5 09:36:04 2021 GMT\"\n        }\n      }\n    },\n    \"authorizer\": {\n      \"jwt\": {\n        \"claims\": {\n          \"claim1\": \"value1\",\n          \"claim2\": \"value2\"\n        },\n        \"scopes\": [\n          \"scope1\",\n          \"scope2\"\n        ]\n      }\n    },\n    \"domainName\": \"id.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com\",\n    \"domainPrefix\": \"id\",\n    \"http\": {\n      \"method\": \"POST\",\n      \"path\": \"/path/to/resource\",\n      \"protocol\": \"HTTP/1.1\",\n      \"sourceIp\": \"192.168.0.1/32\",\n      \"userAgent\": \"agent\"\n    },\n    \"requestId\": \"id\",\n    \"routeKey\": \"$default\",\n    \"stage\": \"$default\",\n    \"time\": \"12/Mar/2020:19:03:58 +0000\",\n    \"timeEpoch\": 1583348638390\n  },\n  \"body\": \"eyJ0ZXN0IjoiYm9keSJ9\",\n  \"pathParameters\": {\n    \"parameter1\": \"value1\"\n  },\n  \"isBase64Encoded\": true,\n  \"stageVariables\": {\n    \"stageVariable1\": \"value1\",\n    \"stageVariable2\": \"value2\"\n  }\n}"
}

However, when I test with Postman, the response is:
curl --location 'https://site.amazonaws.com/beta/KlikyTestAPI' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Accept: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: ••••••'

Postman Response:
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "body": "{}"
}

I don't why is empty
Need help to resolve this

Note that curl is not postman. How are you supplying the request body?

You are not sending any body with Postman (or curl) and your Lambda Function is returning the empty body as response:
  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(event, null, 2), // Pretty-print the JSON
  };

As you see in the response returned by API Gateway, it is the test event provided by API Gateway.
